# MERN stack app deployed on Heroku not showing donut svg charts (it works on localhost)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, svg, mern, donut-chart

I have created a statistics page that presents svg donut chart components (the package is react-donut-component) but on heroku the statistics do not appear. Below are the screenshots of heroku and localhost.

[image: HEROKU][image: LOCALHOST]

**STATISTICS COMPONENTS**

***GameChart.js***

```
import { DonutMultiple, DonutElement } from 'react-donut-component';

function DonutChartGame(props) {
  const { values } = props;
  const colorsArr = ['#c2f158', '#82aac5', '#e93c42'];

  return (
    <div className="game-donut-container">
      <h5>Games</h5>
      <DonutMultiple linecap="butt" size={150} strokeWidth={20} animate={true}>
        <DonutElement color={colorsArr[0]} name={values[0].status}>
          {values[0].value}
        </DonutElement>
        <DonutElement color={colorsArr[1]} name={values[1].status}>
          {values[1].value}
        </DonutElement>
        <DonutElement color={colorsArr[2]} name={values[2].status}>
          {values[2].value}
        </DonutElement>
      </DonutMultiple>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DonutChartGame;
```

***TournamentChart.js***

```
import { DonutMultiple, DonutElement } from 'react-donut-component';

function DonutChartTournament(props) {
  const { values } = props;
  const colorsArr = ['#b834c6', '#1077c3'];

  return (
    <div className="game-donut-container">
      <h5>Tournaments</h5>
      <DonutMultiple linecap="butt" size={150} strokeWidth={20} animate={true}>
        <DonutElement color={colorsArr[0]} name={values[0].status}>
          {values[0].value}
        </DonutElement>
        <DonutElement color={colorsArr[1]} name={values[1].status}>
          {values[1].value}
        </DonutElement>
      </DonutMultiple>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DonutChartTournament;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that nothing can make it work. The only solution was to replace the react-donut-component package with react-chartjs-2.